# Array declaration and initialization in Java. Arrays behave differently, when the position of their subscript indices is changed in their declaration

Tags: java, arrays

The following is the obvious and usual array declaration and initialization in Java.

```
int r[], s[];       //<-------
r=new int[10];
s=new int[10];
```

A very similar case behaves differently, when the position of `[]` is changed in the declaration statement like as shown below.

```
int []p, q[];       //<-------
p=new int[10];
q=new int[10][10];
```

Please look at the declaration. The position of `[]` has been changed from `r[]` to `[]p`. In this case, the array `q` behaves like an array of arrays of type `int` (which is completely different from the previous case).

**The question:** Why is `q`, in this declaration `int []p, q[];` treated as a two dimensional array?

---

**Additional information:**

The following syntax looks wonky.

```
int []a[];
```

This however, complies fine and just behaves like `int a[][];` or `int [][]a;`.

Hence, the following cases are all valid.

```
int [][]e[][][];
int [][][][][]f[][][][];
```

Comment: Try this one `public int numbers()[] { return new int[5]; }` :D

Comment: Ha, it seems my shot in the dark hits the target:)

Comment: Personally, I prefer to declare one array variable per line, and initialize the variable in the same line, in order to avoid this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Look at [JLS on Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2-200):

> The `[]` may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.

and

> Brackets are allowed in declarators as a nod to the tradition of C and C++. The general rules for variable declaration, however, permit brackets to appear on both the type and in declarators, so that the local variable declaration:
>
> ```
> float[][] f[][], g[][][], h[];  // Yechh!
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the series of declarations:
>
> ```
> float[][][][] f;
> float[][][][][] g;
> float[][][] h;
> ```

So for example:

```
int []p, q[];
```

is just

```
int[] p, q[]
```

which is in fact

```
int p[]; int q[][]
```

The rest are all similar.

Comment: It is strange that `q` becomes a two dimension array.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh - It's not strange at all if you pretend that the variables are surrounded by parenthesis, ala Perl's syntax `my $x, $y;` being same as `my($x, $y);`. If you do this theoretical grouping, you get `int[] p, q[]` as `int[] (p, q[])` => commutatively becoming `int[] (p), int[] (q[])` => `int []p, int []q[]` => `int p[], int q[][]`

Answer (score 10):

The sane way of declaring a variable is

```
type name
```

So if type is `int[]`, we should write

```
int[] array
```

Never write

```
int array[]
```

it is gibberish (though it's legal)